# Define pagestyle in preamble based on page number

Tags: header-footer, fancyhdr, preamble

Is there a way to define a page style based on the actual page number? For example, the first page is a title page, second is TOC (possibly third and fourth as well), next is executive summary, next is report, etc.

I am mainly concerned with the first few pages, noting that the page style would have to remain constant for the TOC regardless of how many pages it works out to be.

I would like to accomplish this in my `preamble.tex` file.

Comment: How do you distinguish between your ToC and what follows? Do you issue something like `\mainmatter`? Let us know. Also how different are the page styles relating to the ToC and what follows?

Comment: @Werner - I had not been using \mainmatter. I was instead using \newpage after \tableofcontents. I am not familiar with \mainmatter. The title page may actually need to be a separate .tex file because it would be very different than the ToC and ES. But ToC and ES could be identical in theory, but I may need to change the format slightly.

Answer (score 1):

In principle one can set a page style to be executed as part of another command and therefore tie the two together.

For example, let's assume you have one page style for the ToC called `tocpagestyle` and another for your main matter called `mainmatterpagestyle`. The following would ensure a different page style for the ToC and main matter from your preamble:

```
\let\oldtableofcontents\tableofcontents% Copy \tableofcontents
\renewcommand{\tableofcontents}{% Update \tableofcontents to...
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{tocpagestyle}% Set the ToC page style
  \oldtableofcontents% Set the regular ToC
  \cleardoublepage
  \pagestyle{mainmatterpagestyle}% Set the main matter page style
}
```

One could also tie into `\mainmatter`, if it is used.

Comment: I will try what you have proposed. Is the \cleardoublepage clearing the pagestule for two pages? Have you assumed the ToC will be no longer than two pages?

Comment: @Prevost: `\cleardoublepage` will clear to a recto page in `twoside` mode, or defaults to `\clearpage` in non-`twoside` mode. The above solution makes no assumption of the `\tableofcontents` size (page-wise), and should work for anything. If not, give some more details.